# How do I change this code so it will correctly add up the numbers if numbers are given, concatenates strings if two strings are given

Tags: python-3.x

```
try:
    reply1 = input('Please enter a number: ')
    reply2 = input('Please enter a number: ')
    total = int(reply1) + int(reply2)
    print(f'Sum = {total}')
except ValueError:
    print('Please supply integers')
```

This is the code I am using.

Comment: use `while` loop till invalid input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This maybe?

```
try:
    inp1 = input('Please enter a number: ')
    inp2 = input('Please enter another number: ')

    print(f'Sum = {int(inp1) + int(inp2)}')

except ValueError:
    print(f'Sum = {inp1 + inp2}')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `str.isnumeric()`

```py
reply1 = input('Please enter a number: ')
reply2 = input('Please enter a number: ')

if reply1.isnumeric() and reply2.isnumeric():
  print(f'sum = {int(reply1) + int(reply2)}')
else:
  print(reply1 + reply2)
```

here is some output:

tow numbers:

```
Please enter a number: 12
Please enter a number: 14
sum = 26
```

two strings:

```
Please enter a number: abc
Please enter a number: xyz
abcxyz
```

number and string:

```
Please enter a number: 123
Please enter a number: abc
123abc
```